# bootstrap JS and data-toggle="buttons-checkbox" showing divs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i'm trying to toggle divs using bootstrap (data-toggle="buttons-checkbox") See my code:

```
<div class="btn-group d1" data-toggle="buttons-checkbox">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link ra">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link rb">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link rc">C</button>
</div>

<div class="myDiv rad">AAAAAAAAAAAA<br />AAAAAAAAAAAA</div>
<div class="myDiv rbd">BBBBBBBBBBBB<br />BBBBBBBBBBBB</div>
<div class="myDiv rcd">CCCCCCCCCCCC<br />CCCCCCCCCCCC</div>

$(".ra").on("click",function(){
    $('.myDiv').toggle();
    $(".rad").toggle();
});

$(".rb").on("click",function(){
    $('.myDiv').toggle();
    $(".rbd").toggle();
});

$(".rc").on("click",function(){
    $('.myDiv').toggle();
    $(".rcd").toggle();
});
```

See working link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlody/KZBNh/1/)

any idea how to display it base on the choose ? like 2 divs in the same time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over buttons, find only "active" and show elements that correspond to "active" elements, others hide. If nothing "active" show everything.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/KZBNh/3/

```
var buttons = $(".btn-link");
buttons.on("click",function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('sel');
    buttons.each(function(i,e) {
        var $this = $(e);
        var current = $("."+($this.attr('class').split(' '))[2]+"d");
        if($this.hasClass('sel')) {
            current.show();
        } else {
            current.hide();
        }
    });
    if($('.sel').length==0) {
        $('.myDiv').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: nice ! var current, can I replace it with different class, with out split ?

Comment: To explain var current selector: it looks like `.rad`. Because you have buttons with classes like this: `btn btn-link ra` I split it by space char " " and take 3rd class (e.g. `ra`). So concatenated is: dot + rX + d = `.rXd`. If you want different classes feel free to construct new naming convention. But without split you won't get this variable letter "a, b, c, ..."

Comment: I would like to add this to my checkbox list  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KZBNh/5/) is there any trick to make it works all together ? what do you think @matty ?

Comment: you did it well, just change in 6 line `($this.attr('class').split(' '))[3]` to `($this.attr('class').split(' '))[2]` - arrays are indexed from 0, you need third "word" so you need index 2